# JavaScript saving checkbox value to an array (localstorage) repeats itself during for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, local-storage

Sorry for the not explanatory title.
So here is my problem, im trying to save the values of checkboxes that are checked in an array(localstorage) but here is the problem:
CODE
HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="A"> A<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="B"> B<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="C"> C<br>
        <br><br>
        <a href="#" onclick="getValue();return false;">Get Value</a>

        <script>
            function getValue() {
                var myArray = [];
                var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checks');
                var str = '';

                for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                    if ( checks[i].checked === true ) {
                        str += checks[i].value + " ";
                        myArray.push(str);
                        localStorage.setItem('str',JSON.stringify(myArray));
                    }
                }
            }

        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

if i check the checkbox A and B it will store the value in the localstorage but in this format **["A","A B"]**
which is not right. What im expecting is **["A B"]**.

Thanks in advance
Sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the checked values to the same string, and then push the string. So if the 3 checkboxes are marked the array would be:

```
["A", "A B", "A B C"]
```

Instead push the current checked value into the array, and after the loop ends [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the values, and add to local storage.

Another minor improvement is to select and iterate just the checked boxes, by using [`document.querySelectorAll('.checks:checked')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```js
function getValue() {
  var myArray = [];
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll('.checks:checked');
  
  if(!checks.length) return; // if none were checked return from the function
  
  for (i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
    myArray.push(checks[i].value);
  }
  
  console.log('str', JSON.stringify(myArray)); // localStorage.setItem in the real 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="A"> A<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="B"> B<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="C"> C<br>
  <br><br>
  <a href="#" onclick="getValue();return false;">Get Value</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Just run into another problem, After joining the array. The localstorage(array) wont accept anymore entry.

Comment: I don't understand that statement - "The localstorage(array) wont accept anymore entry". Do you need to add the checked to an existing checked values?

Comment: I chose A B it got stored in the storage successfully as ["A B"], then I wanted to save C in the storage aswell, so im expecting ["A B", "C"] but it didnt work. When I use JSON.stringify it works but it saves as ["A","B","C"].

Comment: What i should've asked is "How to combine two checkbox values before sending to the localstorage[array]". Sorry

Comment: If you need a stringed array, you should use stringify instead of join. The `str` was a bit misleading :) Check the demo.

Comment: If i check two checkbox the output is ["A","B"] is it possible to make it ["A" "B"] without the ',' using stringify?

Comment: Not directly as this is the JSON representation of an array. You can override the array's [toJSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) method, but that's an overkill. `Use Array.join(' ')`, and add `[` and `]` to the string.